# How to remove Gnome theme completely from Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, gnome, themes

I installed Gnome Desktop theme from Software Center last week. But since I used it and I am having some problem with my keyboard. I tried to remove it from software center but I can still see the Gnome apps and Gnome theme at my login screen. So I want to remove it completely. Please help. This is the screenshot of what I installed.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

as you said If you install it from software center , then from the software center it self you can remove that theme and its very easy one click operation.

Just type what you would like to remove in  the search box of askubuntu and it will list that application and by clicking at that application you can see uninstall button and that will take you to the removing of theme from your system.

for example

[image]

Comment: I tried it. But it still showing me the Gnome icon in the login screen and all the Gnome apps are also there. In the software center it showing me that it is removed.

Comment: @REGZEN just for making sure , can you give me picture of what you have installed ? Thank you.

Comment: @rajaqenupula I uploaded the photo. Software center is showing me that it is removed. I tired 'sudo apt-get purge gnome-shell-*' and theme Gnome theme is removed now but there are still other apps like Boxes and I also used Tweak tool. I removed it but all the changes I made in tweak tool are still there. I think this problem is because of tweak tool.